# how to add quota for new user

Tags: linux, users, quota

I have quota enabled for /. I have two users currently. quota applies to both users.
When add new users say user3. Editing edquota -u user3 won't work? Do i need to run quotacheck after running edquota?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is - yes you need to run quotacheck whenever you add a new user.
HTH somebody